# C - Infinite loop when reading a file

Tags: c

I know this is an easy problem but i can't figure out how to solve this. I was learning about file and when i tried to read a file, it went on in an infinite loop. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{

    FILE *p;

    p = fopen("123.txt", "r");

    char ar[150];   

    while(!feof(p))
    { 
        fgets(ar, 150, p); 
        puts(ar);
    }

    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?s=1|227.2797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *p = fopen("data.txt11", "r");
  if (p == NULL)
  {
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char ar[150];

  while (fgets(ar, 150, p) != NULL)
  {
    puts(ar);
  }

  fclose(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. It didn't go into an infinite loop but i didn't print out anything

Comment: @ThuanNguyen that would be a different question, but is close to impossible. Only "close to" because you might start this from an IDE and just not see the output, or your text file could be empty. Note the solution in this answer will add extra newlines.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen probably the file could not be opened, I edited my answer, try now.

Comment: The file can't be opened. Thank  you very much. I understand it now

Comment: @FelixPalmen it's probably not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) but a dupe of the question: "File X exists but fopen cannot open it" or something like this.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen but [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) still stands

Comment: @Jabberwocky what do you mean? I am new to stackoverflow, did i do something wrong? I know that this is a duplicate question, what can i do to solve this?

Comment: @Jabberwocky indeed, "infinite loop" with the code shown indicates a different problem ... is there a dupe for "why does this code without any error checking not work?" ;)

Comment: @ThuanNguyen it's all fine, the dupe just doesn't explain what you experience, but still applies to the question. Your code is broken because of the wrong use of `feof()` **and** because of not checking for **any** errors.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen no you did nothing wrong while asking your question. And it's not really a duplicate of the question mentioned. What I mean is that checking for end of file as you did it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `feof()`, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) .

Check the return value of `fopen()` whether `fopen()` was success or failed, if `fopen()` returns `NULL` then don't proceed further or don't do any operation with `p`. for e.g

```
FILE *p = fopen("data.txt11", "r");
if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"file doesn't exist\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And check the return value of `fgets()`. From the manual page of `fgets()`

> **RETURN VALUE**
>          `fgets()` return `s` on success, and `NULL` on error or when end
>          of file occurs while no characters have been read.

for e.g

```
char *ptr = NULL;
while( (ptr = fgets(ar,sizeof(ar), p)) != NULL) {  
   printf("%s",ptr);
   /* fgets() copies \n t the end of buffer, if you don't want remove it by some logic */ 
}
```

About what `fgets()` will read, from the manual page

> `fgets()` reads in at most `one less than size` characters from stream
>   and
>          stores  them  into  the `buffer` pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>          `EOF` or a `newline`.  If a newline is read, it is `stored` into the  buffer.